# grunt compass: can importPath be set recursive?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-compass

In one of my projects I want to use some additional SCSS that I added using Bower (normalize-scss). The compass configuration in the gruntfile looks like this (created by backbone generator):

```
compass: {
    options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
        importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
        relativeAssets: true
    },
    dist: {},
    server: {
        options: {
            debugInfo: true
        }
    }
}
```

The main scss file has:

```
@import: 'normalize';
```

When I change the import path in the gruntfile to

```
importPath: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components', '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/normalize-scss'],
```

It works, but I'd prefer not to put every single directory that I might need in here. It seems to me it would be more portable if I could do something like:

```
importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/**'
```

But that fails with the warning: `You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory.`.